# System.setPassword(userId, password) not working in LWC. I am getting an error message as "INVALID_SESSION_ID"

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am calling an Apex method through LWC by passing userId and Password as parameters

Apex Method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean setPassword(ID userId, String password){
    try {
        System.setPassword(userId,password);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug('error  '+e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

LWC:`

```
    setPassword({userId:this.userId, password:this.password}).then((result)=>{
        console.log('result   '+result)
        if(result!=false){
            console.log('Password reset done')
        }
    })`
```

But it is not working, an unexpected exception error is thrown[image]

If I try to execute the method in Anonymous window, the password is getting set successfully. It fails if done through LWC. I am logged in as an Admin user when I run this LWC.

This issue is in Salesforce Known issues, but is there any work around or any user settings I need to do in Org level.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could set up [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) so that you can perform the call as a system administrator.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setBody(
  JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, String> {
      'NewPassword' => password
    }
  )
);
req.setEndpoint('callout:admin/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/User/'+userId+'/password');
HttpResponse res = new http().send(req);
if(res.getStatusCode() == 204) {
  return true;
}
```

Note that, as written, this may be a security risk. Consider using `UserInfo.getUserId()` instead of allowing an arbitrary user Id to be passed in.